# Pygame Help- Newbie In Trouble

Tags: python, pygame

very new to python/pygame and was watching some tutorials on YT. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8bx4nits-o <--- This one specifically, and I came across a problem. I was trying to make a white background as in the Video but I couldn't. I don't know where I went wrong.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('slither')

white = (255, 255, 255)

gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

gameDisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

[IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/20swspu.png[/IMG]

If you could help me i'd really appreciate it! 
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need indentation to put `fill` and `update` inside `while` loop.

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white) # indentation
    pygame.display.update() # indentation
```

Comment: Thank You! It worked. However can I ask why an Indent is needed?

Comment: Because python uses indentation to denote *blocks* of code. In this case, indenting it means that the code is inside the `while` 'block'. In your original code it was on the same level as the `while` block, and so not part of the loop. If you want you can think of more indented code as *belonging* to the code that is immediately before it at the next less level of indentation.

Comment: @J.Doe, you should accept his answer (click the green checkmark) since it solved your problem. That shows people that this is indeed the solution, and that your problem is solved, while also providing people with incentive to answer more questions.